# Create or update field after pre validation middlewares?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a "findOneAndUpdate" query that would fire pre-validate middleware.

These middlewares are needed to validate the given coordinates and create an 'id' field (yes, **not** the '_id' one) when it isn't provided in the request's body.

As you can see below (*see comments in the code*), I'm close, but don't understand why the error thrown by `mongo` is the duplicate key variety.

Maybe promises aren't the way to go here, though they allowed me to come accomplish way more than chained `pre` middlewares.

*Here is my Express route:*

```
/* POST /geolocs */
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {

  Geoloc.create(req.body, function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.status(201).json(post);
  });
});
```

*Here is my schema:*

```
var GeolocSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Point',
      required: true
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true
    }
  },
  count: Number
});

GeolocSchema.index({
  location: '2dsphere'
});
```

*The pre validation middlewares:*

```
// Before validation, check given coordinates for errors.
GeolocSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  coord = this.location.coordinates
  if (this.location.type && coord) {
    if (Array.isArray(coord) && coord.length === 2) {
      lat = coord[1];
      lon = coord[0];
      if ((-90 <= lat && lat <= 90) && (-180 <= lat && lat <= 180)) next();
    }
  }
  var err = new Error('...'); // Long error text, irrelevant here
  err.status = 400;
  next(err);
});

// Then, if no 'id' is given, create it.
GeolocSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  if (!this.id) {
    strLat = this.location.coordinates[1].toFixed(3).replace('.', '_');
    strLon = this.location.coordinates[0].toFixed(3).replace('.', '_');
    this.id = strLat + '-' + strLon;
  }
  next();
});
```

What I would love to be able to do is add the following below the above:

```
// Here, using the validate or save hook doesn't change anything.
GeolocSchema.pre('validate', function(next) {
  var prom = Geoloc.findOne({
    'id': {
      $eq: this.id
    }
  }).exec();

  prom.then((err, geoloc) => {  // Arrow function here to access 'this'
    if (err) next(err);
    // If no geoloc was found, go ahead and save.
    if (!geoloc) next();

    // Else, update to increment the count (THIS WORKS).
    return Geoloc.update({'id': this.id}, {$inc: {count: 1}}).exec();

  }).then((toto) => {    
    // This doesn't work, the error thrown by mongo is a duplicate key error (E11000).
    if (toto) next(new Error('204'));
    else next(new Error("Something that shouldn't happen, happened..."));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `pre()` & `post()` middleware for `save` & `validate` are not executed by `update()`, `findOneAnUpdate()` etc. Its mentioned in the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes) as well as there is a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/964)

However, there is `pre('findOneAndUpdate')` and `post('findOneAndUpdate')` hooks available (not sure if the hook for `update` works).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, I know. Pretty sure I've read almost all doc on the subject by now :-D However, to perform a `find` operation I need the `id` which is built in a pre validation step... Or am I missing something?

Comment: Also, I think there is indeed an `update` hook. See [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#notes).

Comment: Yes, but if you read the issue on that Github link given, there is a comment by the developers that the hook for update is not their yet. The best would be to try and see. If it works, its there. If it doesn't then trouble starts! :-)

Comment: Sorry to leave you hanging, I reworked my code to make use of the findOneAndUpdate hook... and hit a bug in the process (see [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4913) ) and some other inconsistencies. Still investigating.
Your answer, while addressing my problem doesn't answer my question. I  upvoted it but will wait a bit before accepting it :-)
Thank you !

Comment: No issues about leaving me hanging. The objective is to solve your problem. By the way, the function executing the rest of the code is after calling `next()` is not a bug. You have to call `return;` after calling `next()` if the call is somewhere in the middle of the function. Probably `return next()` will also work.

Comment: Well, it works as expected in the code above. I answered you on the issue :-)

Comment: Thanks again for your help, after a few more tests this morning I posted the working code as a separate answer below. However, yours is what pointed me in the right direction and is therefor accepted.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the accepted answer by Santanu Biswas, here is the working code based upon it:

**Note that there are still some quirks with it, notably regarding what is sent back to the client in the response, but the MongoDB operation(s) happen as expected.**

*Express route*:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Geoloc.findOneAndUpdate({
    id: req.body.id
  }, req.body, {
    runValidators: true,  // MANDATORY OPTION
    upsert: true,
    context: 'query'      // MANDATORY OPTION
  }, function(err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.status(201).json(post);
  });
});
```

*Pre* `findOneAndUpdate` *middlewares*:

```
GeolocSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {

  doc = this.getUpdate();

  coord = doc.location.coordinates;
  if (doc.location.type && coord) {
    if (Array.isArray(coord) && coord.length === 2) {
      lat = coord[1];
      lon = coord[0];
      if ((-90 <= lat && lat <= 90) && (-180 <= lat && lat <= 180)) {
        return next();
      }
    }
  }
  var err = new Error('...'); // Long error text, irrelevant here
  err.status = 400;
  next(err);
});
```

*And:*

```
GeolocSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', function(next) {
  doc = this.getUpdate();
  query = this.getQuery();

  if (!query.id) {
    strLat = doc.location.coordinates[1].toFixed(3).replace('.', '_');
    strLon = doc.location.coordinates[0].toFixed(3).replace('.', '_');
    query.id = strLat + '-' + strLon;
    doc.id = query.id;
  }

  var prom = Geoloc.findOne({
    'id':query.id
  }).exec();

  prom.then((geoloc, err) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!geoloc) return next();

    doc.count += geoloc.count;

    next();
  });
});
```